# Bandsaw blade keeps drifting and slipping

Tags: band-saw, blade

I just purchased a Rikon 10-inch bandsaw. The blade keeps slipping. I have still to plug the machine if the blade would stay on the wheel.

I follow the following steps:

I lock the tension lever. There is a knob to further adjust the tension on the blade. On this machine there is no gauge to tell me how much to tense the blade. I tense it till a 1/4 inch deflection. Sometimes this is as much as the knob will turn.

I then rotate the wheel by hand and adjust the tracking knob.

No matter how much I adjust the blade keeps drifting either to the front or back of the wheel, and eventually slips off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried to contact Rikon and got no response.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. What kind of research have you done on this before asking? I know there are a great many things out there on this subject (possibly into the hundreds). And SE values Questions where it's clear the OP has done some prior research, which they'll refer to in the body of the Question, so we know what you've seen and/or tried that *didn't* solve the problem for you.

Comment: It sounds like you have never run this bandsaw before, and this is first setup. If you have followed the instructions for setup and something appears wrong, then you should insist that the manufacturer determine if this is a warranty condition. Bandsaws aren't rocket surgery, though tracking can be tricky once the wheels/tires get worn in. A brand-new wheel should be able to track with appropriate settings. Otherwise, you need to find out if this is a warranty problem.

Comment: You also don't mention the model number or the size and gauge of the blade. The latter can be such that some models can't track at all. The assumption here is that you are using the blade that came with the saw, but we can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the newer model of this saw - Rikon model 10-3061.

It sounds like you have read the directions and are following the instructions.

For tracking you have just one knob to turn so you have to play with it until the blade tracks correctly.

For tension you put the quick release lever to "On" and then there is just one knob to turn. As you said 1/4 inch deflection is the goal.

If nothing works you need to:

- take it back to the store
- seek help from a dealer for the tool
- have a friend who is familiar with bandsaws take a look at it

For reference here is the page:

Page [14 of the manual](https://www.rikontools.com/wp-content/uploads/10-3061M2_EN.pdf)

[image]